# dplyr group_by not working inside of function in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have a large data set with each subject identified by a code and each has several observations of the same variable over many dates. I am working on a function to provide some summary data for each ID, but group_by in the function is not working. I get the average for all IDs instead of the average for each ID. One other caveat is that I am trying to get the average of some of the baseline data which is why I have arrange() and slice() included. Here's some code that reproduces the problem.

```
ID <- c("3432q5","233453","q45432")
Date <- as.Date(c("2023-01-01","2023-01-01","2023-01-01","2023-01-02","2023-01-02","2023-01-02","2023-01-03","2023-01-03","2023-01-03"))
Value <- c(3,3,5,2,3,2,4,5,4)
test.df <- data.frame(ID=ID,Date=Date,Value=Value)
Test_fxn <- function(df, variable){
  df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    arrange(Date) %>% 
    slice(1:2) %>% 
    mutate(m=mean(variable))}
test_fxn_df <- Test_fxn(test.df,Value)
```

This results in a mean value of 3.44 for all 3 IDs, but I want the mean for each ID separately.

Comment: Use `mutate(m=mean({{variable}}))`. Those curly brackets should make the difference. See the dup for why. You can also check out the [programming with dplyr guide](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)